# Several Arrays to multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

This might have been asked before, I just don't know how to search for this specific scenario.

I have several arrays (always the same length)

```
array1 = [value1a1, value2a1, value3a1];
array2 = [value1a2, value2a2, value3a2];
array3 = [value1a3, value2a3, value3a3];
```

that I need to combine to one multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
multiArray = [
                [value1a1, value1a2, value1a3],
                [value2a1, value2a2, value2a3],
                [value3a1, value3a2, value3a3]
];
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Show your attempt, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var merge = function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        var intermediate = [];
        for (var j in arguments) intermediate.push(arguments[j][i]);
        result.push(intermediate);
    }
    return result;
};
```

This function accepts any number of arguments, provided all arguments are arrays with exactly three keys. They will be merged according to the description in the question.

Answer (score 6):

```
var multiArray = [];
multiArray.push(array1);
multiArray.push(array2);
multiArray.push(array3);
```

[Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Or even:

```
var multiArray = [array1, array2, array3];
```

[JSFiddle example of 2nd approach](https://jsfiddle.net/48qbfja5/1/)

@MartijnOtto was right, my previous solutions were wrong. I didn't read carefully. I've created a [new JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48qbfja5/3/) with this code:

```
var array1 = ["value1a1", "value2a1", "value3a1", "value4a1"];
var array2 = ["value1a2", "value2a2", "value3a2", "value4a2"];
var array3 = ["value1a3", "value2a3", "value3a3", "value4a3"];

var arrays = [array1, array2, array3];
var multiArray = [];

// initialize 2D array
for (var i=0; i<arrays[0].length; i++) {
    multiArray[i] = [];   
}
// fill values
for (var i=0; i<arrays.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<arrays[i].length; j++) {
        multiArray[j].push(arrays[i][j]);
    }
}

result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(multiArray, null, 2);
```

**Edit**: there was another minor error with indices. Fixed it in JSFiddle and code here to also work with unproportional array sizes (e.g.: `arrays.length === 3` and `arrays[i].length === 4`.

Comment: This is wrong. The question is about making a multidimensional array where the first array consists of the first entry of all the other arrays, the second of all the second entries.

Comment: @MartijnOtto can you explain what you mean? OP in the example seems to want what wullxz approach does

Comment: In his multiArray variable, the first entry should be [value1a1, value1a2, value1a3], which are the first entries of array1, array2 and array3. The given answer would result in the first entry being [value1a1, value2a1, value3a1], which is different.

Comment: got it now, thanks for that hint @MartijnOtto, added correct solution and JSFiddle link